# LDAP authentication over the web using Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, ldap, swift2

I'm working on an iOS app and need to implement user authentication over the internet. We are running an LDAP service on an IBM Domino backend. We are also using Swift for the app.
I have looked up many tutorials, examples, etc. about using openLDAP libraries, however the problem lies in the fact that everything is in Objective-C.
My question is: Is there anyway to implement LDAP user authentication over the internet in an iOS app written in Swift? An Apple library, openLDAP or something similar.

At the time of writing the question, I couldn't find anything online or in the Apple documentation.

Thank you

Comment: Marwin, Apple LDAP offering is called Open Directory; don't know if you truly have access to this on IOS but worth investigating maybe. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Swift/OpenDirectory.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up and report back

Comment: You might consider some sort of gateway service too; although we're talking middleware almost here. This post on stack exchange looks promising. http://serverfault.com/questions/372112/is-there-a-simple-ldap-to-http-gateway-out-there

Comment: Why not just use the objective c libraries from Swift?

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, we're considering that too, we're just hesitant about it because the whole team has no Objective-C knowledge (not that we'll actually need to code anything in it for the import) and we thought it only makes sense for some similar libraries to be available in Swift